# MediaWiki: show bots in recent changes by default?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extension

I am running some pywikibot code on a couple of wikis. I constantly find myself going to `[[Special:Recentchanges]]` and then clicking the "show bots" link (which adds `&hidebots=0` as a parameter).

Is it possible to turn the default display of bot edits in MediaWiki's recent changes?

It's not part of MediaWiki core, but I guess it could be done through an extension and possibly there's another way I didn't think of (though I guess `[[MediaWiki:Common.js]]` is not gonna do much).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a preference for Special:Watchlist which you can set for yourself on [[Special:Preferences#mw-prefsection-watchlist]] or for everyone with [`$wgDefaultUserOptions`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDefaultUserOptions) but it's already default:

```
$wgDefaultUserOptions['watchlisthidebots'] = 0;
```

There is however [no such preference for Special:RecentChanges yet](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T29050), so you have to bookmark the URL. It will be part of future versions of MediaWiki though: [Ensure consistency of how special pages [et al.] switches can be saved (tracking)](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T33882).